# Cross-compiling Python 3.5.1 for Android4.9: cc1: unrecognized command line option '-mssse3'

Tags: android, python, gcc, android-ndk, qpython

I am trying to compile Python3.5.1 for Android4.9 on a 64 bits processor. This is to update the Python interpreter of QPython3.

I started from the [HOWTO file](https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython3-core/blob/master/HOWTO) that describes the steps to follow in the QPython sources.

I have downloaded the Android NDK (r11c) and produced a standalone toolchain. I added the neceesary directories to PATH, and got a first error saying `i686-linux-android-gcc: command not found`.

I solved it by adding `path_to_NDK/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin` to the PATH.

A second error was `cc1: command not found` and I solved it by adding `path_to_NDK/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/libexec/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/` to the PATH.

Now I get stuck on the following errors when compiling openssl:

```
i686-linux-android-gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS  -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -Wa,--noexecstack -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-mssse3'
cc1: error: unrecognized argument in option '-mtune=intel'
cc1: note: valid arguments to '-mtune=' are: arm1020e arm1020t arm1022e  arm1026ej-s arm10e arm10tdmi arm1136j-s arm1136jf-s arm1156t2-s arm1156t2f-s arm1176jz-s arm1176jzf-s arm2 arm250 arm3 arm6 arm60 arm600 arm610 arm620 arm7 arm70 arm700 arm700i arm710 arm7100 arm710c arm710t arm720 arm720t arm740t arm7500 arm7500fe arm7d arm7di arm7dm arm7dmi arm7m arm7tdmi arm7tdmi-s arm8 arm810 arm9 arm920 arm920t arm922t arm926ej-s arm940t arm946e-s arm966e-s arm968e-s arm9e arm9tdmi cortex-a12 cortex-a15 cortex-a15.cortex-a7 cortex-a5 cortex-a53 cortex-a57 cortex-a57.cortex-a53 cortex-a7 cortex-a8 cortex-a9 cortex-m0 cortex-m0plus cortex-m1 cortex-m3 cortex-m4 cortex-r4 cortex-r4f cortex-r5 cortex-r7 ep9312 fa526 fa606te fa626 fa626te fa726te fmp626 generic-armv7-a iwmmxt iwmmxt2 marvell-pj4 mpcore mpcorenovfp native strongarm strongarm110 strongarm1100 strongarm1110 xscale
cc1: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=i686'
cc1: note: valid arguments to '-march=' are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m armv7ve armv8-a armv8-a+crc iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
<builtin>: recipe for target 'cryptlib.o' failed
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ja/dev/sandbox/qpython3-core-master/openssl/crypto'
Makefile:278: recipe for target 'build_crypto' failed
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
```

This happens during the execution of [this script](https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython3-core/blob/master/openssl/xbuild.sh), just after the `configure` returns without error but saying `All configured for 'linux-elf'`. I have a feeling that something is wrong with `configure` not setting the target properly but I am not 100% sure since I am not familiar with `cc1` options `-mtune` and `-mssse3` (this is a first time encounter and I did not gathered anything usefull by searching the internet).

Can anyone advise on the above?

Comment: While compiling stuff is not hard, perhaps you should read the error messages and note that what valid arguments are, and also maybe ensure that those unrecognized options are not passed to the compiler? Anyway, searching online using terms `compiling python arm android` (`arm` being the CPU, see the `mtune` and `march` valid options) will show pages like [this one](http://www.srplab.com/files/others/compile/cross_compiling_python_for_android.html) that might point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have updated the questionto provide more detail. Compiling is not hard but getting the build environement right with very scarse information from the QPython devs is a bit tricky. I'll try to follow the link's steps and see what I get.